# Read File to Dynamic memory

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file, assign the values to the structure members and then add the values into a dynamic memory allocation. I used a for loop to read all the values and then add them to the dynamic array. It gives me errors while I compile it.

How could I assign the values to the Structure members and at the same time add them to a dynamic array?

I would really appreciate your assistance !! thanks.

Here is my code

```
struct Student
{
    char *name[20];       
    char *gender[10];     
    int   age;           
    char *course[20];       
};

struct elements 
{
    struct Student *s;
    struct elements *next;
};

FILE *file;
char c;
char type[30];

int main(int args, char *arg[])
{
    struct Student *school = (struct Student *)malloc(sizeof(struct Student)); // Dynamic array

    file = fopen(arg[1], "r");  // reading file

    if(file != NULL)
    {
        while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) putchar(c);
        {
            int size;
            int r;
            for (r=0; r<size;r++)
            {
                fscanf("Name: %s", school->name);

                //school->name = Addstudent(); // didn't work
                //printf("names are: %s\n",school->name); // here I want to make sure the value name is in the array
            }
         }
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Unable to open file \n");   
    }
    free(file);
    return 0;
}

char* Addstudent()
{
    char* name;
    fscanf(file, "Name: %s",type ,name);
    return name;
}
```

Here are the Errors

> In function ‘main’: Latest1.c:59:4: warning: passing argument 1 of
>   ‘fscanf’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   /usr/include/stdio.h:449:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE *
>   **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
>
> Latest1.c:59:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fscanf’ from
>   incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   /usr/include/stdio.h:449:12: note: expected ‘const char *
>   **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
>
> Latest1.c:59:4: warning: format not a string literal and no format
>   arguments [-Wformat-security]

Comment: Please format your code to make it easier for us to help you, and include the error messages.  Also, if this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Try compiling with -Wall because there are quite a few errors in the above code that would be pointed out to you automatically.

Comment: have you even tried to read those error messages? it's so obvious what the problem is...

Comment: Couple of things: 

#1: NEVER cast the result of `malloc`
#2: ALWAYS use `fclose` on a `FILE *`, not `free`
#3: Work on your code formatting before you post next time.

Comment: @RussS I have tried doing the warnings but some of them I can't interpret.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes I am trying to learn a new language and some of the errors I do not understand. Thanks

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - why not cast the result of `malloc`?

Comment: @Adam Liss: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this code is probably not doing what you want it to do:

```
while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) putchar(c);
{
  ...
}
```

By fixing the formatting, you can see that it's evaluated as

```
while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
  putchar(c);

{
  ...
}
```

The `while` loop contains only `putchar(c)`, and the code within the braces will be executed only once, after reaching EOF.

It's also usually a bad idea to mix calls to `fgetc()` and `fscanf()`.  It's much safer to read one line at a time into a variable, and then parse the data from the variable:

```
char buf[MAX_LEN];
while (fgets(buf, MAX_LEN, file) != NULL) {
  sscanf(buf, "%s", school->name);
}
```

When you're done reading the file, you need to `fclose` it, not `free` it.

Finally, although you've allocated memory for the elements in the `Student` structure, you *haven't* allocated space for the data that the `name`, `gender`, and `course` pointers will point to.

Answer (score 0):

so many errors with your code;

1. do you really understand what this declares?
   char *name[20]
2. really look closely at this line, this neither an array or what you apparently want to do:
   struct Student *school = (struct Student *)malloc(sizeof(struct Student)); // Dynamic array
3. read the documentation on `fscanf`

(ps sorry if formatting is off, still getting to grips with new phone)